# How do you purify phosphoric acid from cheap commercial (hardware-store) products?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry

I am looking for idea's on how to purify phosphoric acid for lab use, as the the price for reagent grade V's home-use ended with me buying a product designed as a rust-killer for steel... The percentage is actually quite high in this product (being 40%), but the unlisted agents added are obviously not going to result in any useful outcomes in lab use.. Has anyone got any ideas on safe purification method's in this case?

Comment: It may be more expensive than buying a reagent grade acid.

Comment: Depends a lot on your lab use. Also I find 83% technical grade phosphoric acid online for 10€ per liter, five liters for twenty. That's too expensive?